# Extract Azure SQL Database using DataTools utility

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, extract, sql-server-data-tools

I would like to write a utility using VS2017 Data-Tools that would extract an Azure Sql database and create the dacpac on local file storage.

I understand I can use the SQL Server Object Explorer and extract from their but I want to write a c# executable that would do the same thing for me so I can automate it and schedule it to happen weekly.

I need to be able to exclude a few tables but other than that its a straight forward extract. Is this possible and is there an example I can use to get started with? Sorry this is all new to me so not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

found a solution that works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;

private static string excludeSchemas = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeSchemas"];
private static string excludeTables = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcludeTables"];
private static string TableQuery = "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), name FROM sys.tables where SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) not in ({0} ) and name  not in ({1}) order by schema_id,name";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Extract();
}

private static void Extract()
{
    var sourceConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceDbConnection"];
    DacServices svc = new DacServices(sourceConnectionString);

    DacExtractOptions dacExtractOptions = new DacExtractOptions
    {
        ExtractApplicationScopedObjectsOnly = true,
        ExtractReferencedServerScopedElements = false,
        VerifyExtraction = false,
        Storage = DacSchemaModelStorageType.Memory
    };
    var tables = BuildTables();
    var dacPacDest = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DacPacDestination"];
    var sourceDb = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceDbName"];

    svc.Extract(dacPacDest,sourceDb, "Sample DACPAC", new Version(1, 0, 0), "Sample Extract", tables, dacExtractOptions);

}

private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> BuildTables()
{
    var tbls = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    var tblConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceDbConnection"];
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(tblConnection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = string.Format(TableQuery, excludeSchemas, excludeTables);
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tbls.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return tbls;
}
```